# JavaScript/JQuery: store function in an object and execute it

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object, properties

I have a multi-dimensional object like this:

```
objectx = {
    1: {
        name: "first",
        loadFunction: function(target) { 
            $(target).load("http://stackoverflow.com #question", function() {
                // do something else
            });
        }
    },
    2: {
        name: "second",
        loadFunction: function(target) { 
            $(target).load("http://stackoverflow.com #answer", function() {
                // do something else
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Every object brings its own function that loads and formats content from different locations. But how do I call the functions in loadFunction from my program?

By the way, I use [simple PHP proxy](http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/) to load the content, for anyone stumbling upon this and wondering. The example is simplified.

Comment: Your object has syntax error. You are missing `,` after each `name` property

Comment: Just `objectx[1].loadFunction(target);`? If you want to programmatically call all of them, an array to loop would be the better choice though.

Comment: The commas are there, but there was another syntax error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me in the console:

```
var derp = {1: {func: function(msg){console.log(msg);}}}

derp[1].func('hi');
```

In your example, I think the main problem is you're missing a comma before your `loadFunction` property. So your object isn't what you think it is.

Here's an even more directly applicable example. I just executed it in the console, so I know it works.

```
objectx = {
    1: {
        name: "first",
        loadFunction: function(target) { 
            console.log('first: ' + target);
        }
    },
    2: {
        name: "second",
        loadFunction: function(target) { 
            console.log('second' + target);
        }
    }
}

objectx[1].loadFunction('hi');
> first: hi

objectx[2].loadFunction('hi');
> secondhi
```

Perhaps whenever you reference objectx, it's not in the state you think it's in.

Comment: Copy and paste that stuff in the console and execute it. Does it work? if so, your error is not where you think it is.

Comment: Or perhaps `$(target).load` is what's throwing the `not a function` error? I believe this would happen if your jQuery selector is not finding anything.

Comment: You are right. The problem was another syntax error in the object. It works now, thank you!